# Autofiltering Excel with multiple filter conditions

Tags: perl, vbscript, argument-passing

I am trying to autofilter in Excel using the below VBScript code. This script called multiple times from a Perl program.

```vb
Dim objExcel : Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Selection.AutoFilter
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").AutoFilter WScript.Arguments.Item(0), _
    WScript.Arguments.Item (1)
```

Now I would like to know: is there a way by which I can pass an array for `WScript.Arguments.Item (1)` so that all the conditions are selected in one go? The task is to delete the filtered value. I call this script through Perl multiple times and the above script filter one value at a time and delete. The program works fine, but is slow.

Following is the part of Perl which calls the VBScript.

```pl
while(<FILE>){
    chomp;
    system("CSCRIPT "."\"$currentWorkingDirectory\"".'aboveVBS.vbs 9 '."\"$_\"");
    sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put quotes around the values, VBScript will treat it as a single argument.

```
> cscript script.vbs arg1 "multiple values for arg 2"
```

In the script:

```
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Count    ' ==> 2

a = Split(WScript.Arguments(1))
WScript.Echo a(0)                        ' ==> multiple
WScript.Echo a(1)                        ' ==> values
WScript.Echo a(2)                        ' ==> for
WScript.Echo a(3)                        ' ==> arg
WScript.Echo a(4)                        ' ==> 2
```

Excel expects:

```
Range.AutoFilter <Field>, <Criteria>, <Operator>
```

If you want a list of criteria to filter on, you'll use `xlFilterValues` for the `<Operator>` argument. `<Criteria>` will be an array of string values, which we created above.

```
Const xlFilterVaues = 7

objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").AutoFilter WScript.Arguments.Item(0), a, xlFilterValues
```

So, just try adding `Split()` around `WScript.Arguments(1)` in your existing code, and pass `xlFilterValues` for the third param.

Answer (score 0):

If only your second argument changes, you could pass the entire content of your data file to the VBScript:

```pl
local $/;
my $args = <FILE>;
$args =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$args =~ s/\r?\n/" "/g;

system("cscript \"$currentWorkingDirectory\\your.vbs\" 9 \"$args\"");
```

and change the processing in your VBScript to this:

```vb
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbook.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
...
xl.Selection.AutoFilter

For i = 1 To WScript.Arguments.Count - 1
  ws.Range("G1").AutoFilter WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(i)
  ...
Next
```

Or you could simply call the VBScript with the field and the path to the data file:

```pl
system("cscript \"$currentWorkingDirectory\\your.vbs\" 9 \"$filepath\"");
```

and do all the processing in VBScript:

```vb
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbook.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
...
xl.Selection.AutoFilter

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f   = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1))
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  ws.Range("G1").AutoFilter WScript.Arguments(0), f.ReadLine
  ...
Next
f.Close
```

Applying more than 2 AutoFilter conditions to a column at the same time is not possible. Check the signature of the `AutoFilter` method in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx):

> expression .**AutoFilter**(***Field, Criteria1, Operator, Criteria2, VisibleDropDown***)
>
> expression An expression that returns a **Range** object.

You have `Critera1` and `Criteria2` and an `Operator` for combining the two. Calling the `AutoFilter` method with another set of criteria replaces the existing criteria.

Comment: thank you, the above code also filters one value at a time, I should filter all the options in the text file in one go... `ws.Range("G1").AutoFilter WScript.Arguments(0), f.ReadLine` in this case the first filter is removed after the first iteration. so finally the value at the end of the text file will be the final filter.

Comment: @Programmer Your existing code does exactly the same, so I assumed that's what you wanted. If you want to apply all criteria to one column at the same time: that's not possibe. If you take a closer look at the [`AutoFilter` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) or the AutoFilter GUI you'll notice that you can have at most 2 filters for the same column.